# How to update only list of attributes Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There is the following code:

```
@owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
if @owner.update(owner_params)
  # Some actions
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

'Owner' model has name, email, phone and 2 virtual attributes (for has_secure_password) : password and password_confirmation. I want to update only name, email and phone:

```
def owner_params
  params.require(:owner).permit(:name, :email, :phone)
end
```

But when I try to update Owner I get a message about blank password, because I use presence validation for password during creating. Please, tell me, is it possible to update only list of sending attributes passing validations other ones? Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about `hidden_field`? not sure..

Comment: are you using devise for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Devise` for authentication then there is a method named `update_without_password`, do this way

```
@owner.update_without_password(owner_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one helps.

putting `has_secure_password validations: false` would work but you need to make custom validations after it

Answer (score -1):

Use #update_attributes instead. It looks like #update runs the validation for all parameters (even with the missing ones).

Comment: There is no difference between `update` and `update_attributes`, `update` has been introduced in rails 4

Comment: Yes . Batter check before answer